# omitted variable bias in regression with breaks

Tags: least-squares

Take a DGP

$y_t = \alpha + \beta_1 * X_{1,t} * D_{[t\leq\bar{t}]} + \beta_2 * X_{1,t} * D_{[t\geq\bar{t}]} + \beta_3 * X_{2,t} * D_{[t\leq\bar{t_2}]} + \beta_4 * X_{2,t} * D_{[t\geq\bar{t_2}]} +\epsilon_t$.

Suppose I estimate instead

$y_t = \mu + \beta_5 * X_{1,t} * D_{[t\leq\bar{t}]} + \beta_6 * X_{1,t} * D_{[t\geq\bar{t}]} + \beta_7 * X_{2,t}+\eta_t$.

Under what circumnstances will we have an omitted variable problem that biases $\beta_5$ and $\beta_6$? Or, if you prefer, under what circumsntances, won't we have a bias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer would be:

re-write the DGP as follows by setting $\beta_4=\beta_3+\delta$

$y_t = \alpha + \beta_1 * X_{1,t} * D_{[t\leq\bar{t}]} + \beta_2 * X_{1,t} * D_{[t\geq\bar{t}]} + \beta_3 * X_{2,t} + \delta*X_{2,t}*D_{[t\geq\bar{t_{2}}]}$. Provided $\delta\neq 0$ and $cov(X_{2,t}*D_{[t\geq\bar{t_{2}}]},.)\neq 0$ where the dot denotes other regressors, we have an omitted variable bias.